# How can I convert a large ANSI text file to UTF-8?

Tags: windows, utf-8, ansi, conversion

For a database migration I need a tool which can convert a 1 GB file from Ansi codepage to UTF8 on Windows. Maybe I can use sed (given that I know all search and replace values), but is there something included in GNU or Windows tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANSI? Did you mean CP1252?

[iconv](http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/), [for Win32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libiconv.htm).